# Vue3, Pinia, Axios - Unable to post object from store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

I'm completely baffled by this, maybe I've been looking at it for so long now.

I'm trying to send POST data to an API using axios inside the pinia store. This is working with staticly assigned parameters but I have instances where I need to post various user-configured key values.

So here's a working example:

```js
async resetPassword(selector, token, password) {
  var params = new URLSearchParams()
  params.append('selector', selector)
  params.append('token', token)
  params.append('password', password)

  return axios.post(
    import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL + '/reset-password/confirm',
    params
  )
}
```

This works fine, payload is sent over to the API and everything is happy.

When I'm trying to send dynamically assigned data (this is assigned to the pinia store as a form is filled out)

```js
async submitDataValues() {
  const values = this.newData
  var params = new URLSearchParams()
  for (var k in values) {
    var val = values[k]
    if (isObject(val)) {
      val = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, val))
    }
    params.append(k, val)
  }

  if (
    values?.eventid == null &&
    this.eventId !== null &&
    this.eventId !== 'new'
  ) {
    params.append('eventid', this.eventId)
  }

  return await axios
    .post(import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL + '/event/' + this.dataContext, params)
    .then(async (response) => {
      //...
    })
}
```

The above does not work, the length of the object is `0` but the object has items assigned against it, a console log shows that the object has key/values assigned but when I try and access it, its showing as a `0` length.

What's also strange is that this worked absolutely fine up until it was deployed to production so I had no idea that this didn't work until yesterday.

It's worth noting that I've tried initialising `params` as an `Object`, `URLSearchParams` and tried `JSON.stringify`

**It seems the problem is that I cannot loop over the object or copy it, but I can see the values within it.**

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: "but I can see the values within it" - how exactly? console isn't the best way to debug, especially if it's misused. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. So the app is in production mode so I'm unable to debug any further, this issue is not present when I run the app in dev mode. I can do console.log(this.newData) and see that it has properties inside [[Target]] but the value of length is zero. So my guess is that it isn't looping over the object because it thinks that there are zero properties? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: "console.log(this.newData)" - this is a mistake, this is explained in linked question. Use JSON stringify or better use a debugger which exists in most browsers and IDEs, you're able to use breakpoints in any environment. Sounds like the problem is that there's race condition that makes the keys to not exist when you access them, and you didn't debug this properly

Comment: It's also worth noting that in your action, you're using the store's data references directly, so you update the store values and not a copy. Hence your action has side effects. But that would not explain why the length is 0. As suggested by Estus, you'd need more in depth debugging here.